# CreateFileMapping is used to create shared memory in win32

Tags: c, win32-process

CreateFileMapping is used to create shared memory in win32. Do need to synchronized shared memory read/write or it is done automatically ?

Comment: It is a very strange question, running CreateFileMapping() on more than one thread doesn't make much sense.  You have to wait until you get the HANDLE back before you can use it.  The other process calls OpenFileMapping instead.  This needs to be synchronized, you cannot open a mapping that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Maybe the OP means whether the access of different threads/processes to the shared memory is automatically synchronised?

Comment: Yes, I mean whether shared memory needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not clear about whether you use this for shared memory between threads or processes, so just to be sure: for threads you dont need a file-mapping, all memory in a single process is visible to all threads (and needs sync).

To use it for shared memory between processes: yes you have to sync accesses to it explicitly because the system can not know whether consecutive writes to it are meant to be grouped as a single transaction or not. Tip to do this: To sync them you can not use criticalsections (they only work for threads within a process), you could use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937%28v=VS.85%29.aspx